# How to catch exception to backtrack(or Delimited Continuations) in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and trying to know some example for catch/3.

The code I want to run is here. (Using swi-prolog v8.0.3)

mylib.pl

```
mylib([1,2]).
mylib(1).
test(X):- mylib(X), length([1],X).
```

then consult it in swipl then run the following command.

```
catch(test(X),error(Err,_Context),format('catch')).
```

So here I want to catch the `typeError exception` and get `X = 1`. But the result is catching the exception and nothing continues. So what should I do to reach my target?

Running messages here.

```
catch
Err = type_error(integer, [1, 2]),
_Context = context(length/2, _12488).
```

UPDATE1:
I have tried to modify the mylib.pl to the following:

```
mylib([1,2]).
mylib(1).
test(X):- mylib(X),catch(length([1],X),error(Err,_Context),format('catch')).
```

Then run `test(X).` command and got following result.

```
?- test(X).
catch
X = [1, 2] ;
X = 1.
```

But what I want is skipping the `X = [1, 2]`

UPDATE2:
[got this from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/comments/ax9de3/catch_exception_but_still_do_backtracking/)
I'm exploring the usage of reset/3 and shift/1. It will be great if someone could give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use Prolog's inbuilt failure and backtracking:

```
mylib([1,2]).
mylib(1). 
test(X):- 
    mylib(X),
    integer(X), % will fail on list, backtrack until a passing value for X is found, i.e. 1
    length([1],X).
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well in this case. But it seems hard if the predicate becomes more complex. So I wonder if expection handling will work.

Comment: If you're using `catch/3`, chances are you're fighting the language instead of working with it. In this case you've already got an unwise predicate in `mylib/2` as it returns 2 different data structures, you can circumvent this with proxy-predicates that filter by type, or handle it in use. Better is to change your data representation as it'll hurt less in the long run. `catch/3` has implicit cuts and the recovery is expensive, you only use it when dealing with stuff you can't control that'll make your program blow-up, that's when it's hard and becomes complex. Use the language as intended.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Indeed I have thought encoding the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Only a few Prolog systems provide shift/reset, mostly those that use it for recursive tabling. But if your Prolog system does not have shift/reset, you might help yourself with a [meta-interpreter](https://gist.github.com/jburse/ecdb7698a060683573dc08161143334a#gistcomment-3079420):

```
solve([], ok).
solve([shift|Y], S) :- !, S = stop(Y).
solve([reset(X,Y)|Z], S) :- !, solve(X, Y), solve(Z, S).
solve([X|Y], S) :- rule(X, L, Y), solve(L, S).
```

The above returns ok or stop(continuation), depending whether a shift/0 happened or not. The continuation is delimited with reset/2. To have a throw ball, extend it to shift/1 and reset/3.

See also:

**Delimited Continuations in Prolog - Schrijvers et. al, 2012**
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ba6d/b9ffde4052536a8237486cf82933e6bd97d5.pdf